# Incompatible types required int but found void

Tags: java

Im am trying to get a dice to roll in my code, but when i put in the dice and try to roll it, it says incompatible types.

```
package domain;

public class Dice {
    /**
     * creating integers for 2 dice and sum of these
     */
    private int dice1, dice2, sum;

    /**
     * Gets the number of die1
     */
    public int getDie1() {
        return dice1;
    }

    /**
     * Gets number of die2
     */
    public int getDie2() {
        return dice2;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the sum of both dice
     */
    public int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }

    /**
     * Rolls the dice and gets sum for both dice
     */
    public void rollDice() {
        dice1 = rollDice();
        dice2 = rollDice();
        sum = (dice1 + dice2);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * Makes the dice roll randomly from 1-6
     */
    private int rollDie() {return (int) ((Math.random()*6));}
```

Comment: `dice1 = rollDice()` should probably be `dice1 = rollDie()`. Looks like a simple typo question.

Comment: You mean to call `rollDie()`, not `rollDice()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are useing the wrong method. You are using `rollDice()` instead of `rollDie()`.

Change it to this:

```
public void rollDice() {
    dice1 = rollDie();
    dice2 = rollDie();
    sum = (dice1 + dice2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are calling a wrong method. Use `rollDie()` instead of `rollDice()`.

```
 /**
     * Rolls the dice and gets sum for both dice
     */
    public void rollDice() {
        dice1 = rollDie();
        dice2 = rollDie();
        sum = (dice1 + dice2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the rollDice() function has a void return type, which you're assigning to the value of dice1, dice2, and sum, which are integers.